# how to view the output of a file with .html.haml extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Please help me, I am working on a rails project and I've created a view file with extension .html.haml but now when I am trying to view the output of that file it is giving an error. Is there any other method to view the files of such extension, I am using the way as i use to view my file with exyension .html.erb. I've created an action in controller nd matches the path in routes.rb. Please help me , Thanks in advance.
My routes.rb file is

```
PretAChef::Application.routes.draw do

  # mount FeatherCms::Engine => "/feathers"

  # get 'pages/:name' => 'feather_cms/pages#published', :as => 'feather_published_page'
  resources :messages, only: [:destroy, :show] do
    member do
      post :reply
      get :mark_read
    end
  end

  resources :bookings, only: [] do
    resources :messages, only: [:new, :create]
  end


    resources :chefs, :only => [:index, :show] do
        member do
      get :feedbacks
    end
  end
  resources :customers, :only => [] do
    member do
      get :feedbacks
    end
  end

  resources :ingredients, only: [:index]

  resources :cuisines, only: [:index]

  resources :home do
    collection do
      post :contact
    end
  end
  root :to => 'home#index'
  match 'contact_us' => 'home#contact_us', :as => :contact_us
    match 'mypop' => 'chefs#mypop', :as => :mypop

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations  => "users/registrations", :sessions => "users/sessions", :passwords => "users/passwords", :confirmations => "users/confirmations", :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks" }

  devise_scope :user do
    match "/chef/sign_up" => "users/registrations#new_chef", as: :chef_sign_up
    match "/chef/sign_in" => "users/sessions#new_chef", as: :chef_sign_in
    match "/users/sign_out" => "users/sessions#destroy", as: :sign_out
  end

  resource :profiles, :only => [:edit, :update] do
  end

  namespace :customer do
    resource :dashboards, only: [:show]
    resources :bookings, :only => [:create, :update, :edit, :destroy] do
      collection do
        get :booking_confirmation
        get :book_chef
      end
      member do
        # TODO: WTF: use destroy for cancelation
        post :rate
        post :comment
        get :feedback
        get :pay
        get :complete
        get :confirm
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :admin do
    resources :messages, only: [:index, :show] do
      collection do
        get :contact_us
        get :messages
      end
    end
    resources :cuisines, except: [:show]
    resources :bookings, only: [:index, :update, :edit, :destroy]


    resources :users, only: [:index, :update, :edit] do
      collection do
        get :active
        get :pending
      end
      resources :menus, except: [:index] do
        collection do
          post :preview
          get :destory_dish_image
        end
      end
      resources :availabilities, only: [:create, :destroy]
      resources :chef_messages, only: [:destroy, :show, :index, :new, :create] do
        member do
          post :reply
          get :mark_read
        end
      end

      namespace :chef do
        resources :bookings, only: [:edit, :update] do
          member do
            get :accept
            post :rate
            post :comment
            get :feedback
          end
        end
      end

    end

    resources :searches, only: [:index] do
      collection do
        get "user"
      end
    end
  end

  namespace :chef do
    resources :bookings, only: [:edit, :update] do
      member do
        get :accept
        post :rate
        post :comment
        get :feedback
      end
    end
    resource :dashboards, only: [:show]
    resources :menus, except: [:index] do
      collection do
        post :preview
        get :destory_dish_image
      end
    end
    resources :availabilities, only: [:create, :destroy]
  end

  # The priority is based upon order of creation:
  # first created -> highest priority.

  # Sample of regular route:
  #   match 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'
  # Keep in mind you can assign values other than :controller and :action

  # Sample of named route:
  #   match 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', :as => :purchase
  # This route can be invoked with purchase_url(:id => product.id)

  # Sample resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Sample resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Sample resource route with more complex sub-resources
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', :on => :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Sample resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'

  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes"

  # This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
  # Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
  # match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
end
```

and my view file is

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    :css
      /* popup_box DIV-Styles*/
      #popup_box { 
          display:none; /* Hide the DIV */
          position:fixed;  
          _position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6 */  
          height:300px;  
          width:600px;  
          background:#FFFFFF;  
          left: 300px;
          top: 150px;
          z-index:100; /* Layering ( on-top of others), if you have lots of layers: I just maximized, you can change it yourself */
          margin-left: 15px;  

          /* additional features, can be omitted */
          border:2px solid #ff0000;      
          padding:15px;  
          font-size:15px;  
          -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
          -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;
          box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ff0000;

      }

      #container {
          background: #d2d2d2; /*Sample*/
          width:100%;
          height:100%;
      }

      a{  
      cursor: pointer;  
      text-decoration:none;  
      } 

      /* This is for the positioning of the Close Link */
      #popupBoxClose {
          font-size:20px;  
          line-height:15px;  
          right:5px;  
          top:5px;  
          position:absolute;  
          color:#6fa5e2;  
          font-weight:500;      
      }
    %title Popup Box DIV
    %script{src: "http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.2.6.min.js", type: "text/javascript"}
    :javascript
      $(document).ready( function() {

          // When site loaded, load the Popupbox First
          loadPopupBox();

          $('#popupBoxClose').click( function() {            
              unloadPopupBox();
          });

          $('#container').click( function() {
              unloadPopupBox();
          });

          function unloadPopupBox() {    // TO Unload the Popupbox
              $('#popup_box').fadeOut("slow");
              $("#container").css({ // this is just for style        
                  "opacity": "1"  
              }); 
          }    

          function loadPopupBox() {    // To Load the Popupbox
              $('#popup_box').fadeIn("slow");
              $("#container").css({ // this is just for style
                  "opacity": "0.3"  
              });         
          }        
      });
  %body
    #popup_box
      / OUR PopupBox DIV
      %h1 This IS A Cool PopUp
      %a#popupBoxClose Close
    #container
      / Main Page
      %h1 sample
```

and my action is mypop in chefs controller.

Comment: @RajeshKolappakam the problem is that I am trying to send it to that action which I've defined to show my haml file bt instead of going to that method it is going to some other method of that controller and showing error in it. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: Can you post your `routes.rb` file

Comment: yes sure i am editing my post.

Comment: post your haml template also

Comment: I've posted both the files please help now.

Comment: please help @RajeshKolappakam i've posted my both files. please tell what wrong I m doing.

Comment: I don't see any `mypop` under the `chefs` resource in your `routes.rb`. Did you forge to add it there?

Comment: I've not used it in chefs resources instead i've used a line  match 'mypop' => 'chefs#mypop', :as => :mypop, is it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have not installed a gem for it. All you need to do is add gem "haml" to your Gemfile. Run bundle install

And you're done.

Comment: I've installed the gem actually the project is done by anyone else and now it has come to me for some modification and i've added a new file from my side into its view folder other files there are also with same extension and they are running.

Comment: I have never user file with .haml extension, i am new to rails nd always used files with .html.erb extension, please suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to place all your css and script under assets and not on the template itself and secondly can you explain your problem a little. I mean what action are you calling, how are you rendering your file and to which action its going

Comment: ok i'll put all my css in my assets secondly the problem is that I am trying to see the output of that mypop.html.haml file and for that i've created an action in chefs controller and matches that path in my routes.rb file as u can see in my routes.rb file bt it is showing error and not showing any o/p.

Comment: the problem is that I am trying to send it to that action which I've defined to show my haml file bt instead of going to that method it is going to some other method of that controller and showing error in it. Please tell me what to do.

Comment: can you be specific and write your full error and secondly i'm asking, from which action you are rendering this template. can you post that action

Comment: Error is:  ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ChefsController#show

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: true: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 0 AND (role = 1 AND confirmed_at IS NOT NULL AND approve = true) LIMIT 1
Rails.root: /Users/sumitkalra1984/pretachef

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/chefs_controller.rb:27:in `find_chef'
Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"mypop"}
Show session dump

Show env dump

Response

Headers:

None

Comment: @IshanSharma from your error what i can see is there's no problem in your haml template. Problem is your action in chefs_controller or to be more specific in line no 27 in your chefs_controller. can you post that action